# Can One Wear Engraved Jewelry?

Tags: halacha, jewelry

Is it okay to wear jewelry that has an animal engraved on it, even if it is slightly raised? What about while davening or in shul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Dei’ah, 141:6, it says that an ingraving of an animal is permitted